# Positioning of Particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am doing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U) where CG Geek shows how to build a realistic city. After about 45 minutes the city has basically been built. And now a few small buildings are created on a separate layer and a Hair particle system is created to grow the small buildings (as a group) out of the roofs of the high rise buildings

[image]

Not all of those small buildings are placed within the boundaries of the roofs. How can I control the positioning of these hairs so that all small buildings are neatly placed at the roofs ?

[image]

Comment: I think ideally, when having a problem with a complex tutorial you need to try and contact the tutorial maker. It will be very difficult for people who haven't already followed the tutorial to work out a solution which fits in to the techniques already used, particularly seeing as there is no indication *what* techniques were used to create this (without following the tutorial). At that the very least I think it requires you to upload your blend file.

Comment: @RayMairlot As you probably know I upload My blend file almost always when I ask à question. I throught iT wouldnot contribute much this time and I tried to formulate My question so that knowledge of the tutorial would be less important. But perhaps You are right

Comment: @RayMairlot About asking THE tutorial makers... I find they most Often  don't answer your question, especially the popular tutorial makers

Comment: @RayMairlot I have added the file, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with several different ways:

**A) Don't have the wrong particles** (Chose one or more)

- Make the houses smaller
- Make less houses
- On rotation, check "normal". If you made your normals right, the houses should align along the faces decreasing the probability of going of an edge
- Adjust the seed until all houses fit in the areas visible in the final render

**B) Cut them in particle edit**

- Go into the [particle edit mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/physics/particles/mode.html)
- Cut all wrong placed houses

**C) Vertex groups**

- Add a new vertex group
- Assign all faces where a house is possibly allowed to stand (leaving a maring of the maximum size of a house in every direction) to that group
- In the particle settings -> Vertex groups, select this group under "density"

**D) Texture (Cycles only)**

- Create a new, empty image.
- Go to orthographic top-down view of your city.
- Select your mesh.
- Go into texture paint mode.
- Paint the areas where houses are allowed.
- Go to particle settings -> Texture
- Create a new texture and go to texture properties
- Link that texture to the image you painted
- Under influence uncheck all but "density"

**E) Remove them manually**

- Apply your particle system.
- Delete wrong houses
- Select the remaining ones and join them (optional)

That's about all the possible ways I could think of. Chose the one you like the most! If I missed a good way, please add it. If something is unclear or you need screenshots, I can add them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very clear answer. I will try the various methods tomorrow